# jquery - Swipe Page Counting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe

I am creating a swipe page system using the library touchSwipe.js.

With the method I have, I can swap between pages however, I cannot figure out to go back to previous page properly.

Right now if I swipe right and left few times the counting system goes out summing the swipes.
How can I make the counting system properly in order to move between pages?

```
var swipeRight = 0;
var swipeLeft = 0;
var swipePage = 0;

function swipe1(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {

  if (direction == "left") {
    swipeLeft++;
    if (swipeLeft == 5) {
      swipeLeft = 0;
    }
  }

  if (direction == "right") {
    swipeRight++;
    if (swipeRight == 5) {
      swipeRight = 0;
    }
  }

  swipePage = swipeLeft - swipeRight;

  if (swipePage == 0) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollLeft: 0,
    }, 1500);
    swipeLeft = 0;
    swipeRight = 0;
  }

  if (swipePage == 1) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollLeft: $("#hwwPage").offset().left
    }, 1500);
  }

  if (swipePage == 2) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollLeft: $("#projPage").offset().left
    }, 1500);
  }

  if (swipePage == 3) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollLeft: $("#digiPage").offset().left
    }, 1500);
  }

  if (swipePage == 4) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollLeft: $("#contPage").offset().left
    }, 1500);
  }

  console.log(swipeRight + "+" + swipeLeft);
  console.log(swipePage);
}
```

Comment: did the answer worked for you?
Made some changes in it

Comment: Thank you Sid, I am not in front of PC right now.. will check in 10 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code: you don't really need swipeleft and swiperight i think. Just increase or decrease the swipePage value depending on the swipe direction:

```
var swipePage = 0;

function swipe1(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {

    if (direction == "left") 
        if (swipePage > 0) 
           swipePage++;

    if (direction == "right") 
        if (swipePage < 4) 
           swipePage--;

    var pageIds = ["",
                   "#hwwPage",
                   "#projPage",
                   "#digiPage",
                   "#contPage"
                  ];
    $("html, body").animate({
       scrollLeft: $(pageIds[swipePage]).offset().left
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your code but it shows with the error   "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element."

Comment: @SNos yeah stupid mistake.. I've fixed it.. but I guess you were already able to do it alone yesterday ;)